# Spool a long strings with zeroes to excel

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, spool

I'm trying to spool query results into excel file. This file doesn't exist yet, it's created when I run the script, so I can't format it before.

I have a problem with a single column, it's a number, but in case that number is NULL I need to provide String of nine zeroes `(000000000)`.

Excel saves those zeroes as a single zero, can I somehow fix that? I tried to adding `TO_CHAR` without any arguments, so excel saves every number as a String instead, but it doesn't work.

`TO_CHAR(NVL(IDNT_NR, '000000000'))`

Also tried:

`NVL(IDNT_NR, CAST(000000000 AS VARCHAR2(9)))`

Tried putting a single quote before zeroes, still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it a `csv` excel or the actual `xls` kind of excel?

Comment: It is a `csv` excel.

Comment: If its a csv, open it in notepad and see. `000000000` should be there.

Comment: Oh, well, it is there, too bad excel couldn't show it tho. Thanks!

Comment: If you generate it in the CSV file as `="000000000"` then it looks OK when opened in Excel; but the cell is actually a formula not a fixed string. That may be an acceptable workaround, but probably not...

Comment: As above, you can write number preceded by a hidden apostrophe like `NVL(IDNT_NR, '''000000000')`, excel will show cell as number, only in formula y'll see apostrophe symbol.

Comment: If the column is a number then Excel is quite right to show a single zero. `'000000000'` is a magic value: frankly `null` is better.

Comment: It's USA standard for TIN number (default is nine zeroes), apostrophe like @Seyran wrote doesn't work, it just prints that string (with apostrophe)

Comment: @Shadov I know what is TIN, I've made FATCA/IRS reporting system, actually they are a lot of TIN kinds  and they are not numbers, they consists of digits, but as an entity  not number.

Comment: Yes, that's why I would want excel to actually show those nine zeroes, even tho number-wise it is the same as a single zero. None of the options worked so far for excel. Before I thought it is saved as a single zero, but as @Nitish suggested I checked in notepad and it's fine, so what excel show doesn't really matter now :)

Comment: @Shadov sorry, I was wrong (English is not my native), I've mixed up single quote with apostrophe, I've same problem with exporting CLOB in TSV format for further showing in excel, so I've done export as formula like this `=CONCATENATE("", "' || my_col_val || '")'`. When it opens in excel it calculates formula and shows value as I want